# Prevent Git Stash from Resetting Staged Files

Tags: git, git-stash

Assume the following scenario:

file `a` and `b` are both modified, and `a` is staged in the index. If you run `git stash` and then `git stash pop`, file `a` is no longer staged.

How you make `git stash` return the index to the previous state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you just need:

```
git stash pop --index
```

Comment: This should really be the default IMHO.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: My first instinct would be to agree, but there's a probable reason, descriped in the manpage: "this can fail, when you have conflicts (which are stored in the index, where you therefore can no longer apply the changes as they were originally)." Arguably it should still be the default when there aren't conflicts, though...